# Calling a C++ virtual method from Rust throws an Access violation error even after it executed successfully

Tags: c++, rust, clang, virtual-functions, vtable

I'm trying to call a virtual method of a C++ object from Rust. I'm getting output, but after the execution of this method, it throws an exception.

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00000001 in testvirtual.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000001.
```

Here's a minimal repro of my issue

```
#include <iostream>
#include<Windows.h>

struct Calculate{
    virtual int sum(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)  Calculate* get_numbers() {
    Calculate* obj = new Calculate();
    return obj;
}

int main() {
    typedef void(func)();
    auto handle = LoadLibrary(TEXT("testvirtualrs.dll"));
    auto address = (func*)GetProcAddress(handle, "execute");
    (*address)();
    return 0;
}
```

Rust:

```
#[link(name = "testvirtual")]
extern "C" {
    fn get_numbers() -> *mut Calculate;
}

#[repr(C)]
pub struct CalculateVtbl {
    pub sum: unsafe extern "C" fn(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32,
}

#[repr(C)]
pub struct Calculate {
    pub vtbl: *const CalculateVtbl,
}

impl Calculate {
    #[inline(always)]
    pub unsafe fn sum(&self, a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
        ((*self.vtbl).sum)(a, b)
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn execute() {
    let a = get_numbers();
    unsafe {
       let val = (*a).sum(5, 6);
       println!("val = {val}");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
val = 11
```

Also I'm using **clang compiler** and x86 arch. Exception thrown after the method is finished calling from Rust, it was kind of ambiguous and it didn't help to find the cause

Comment: Please don't invoke virtual methods without setting the `this` pointer.

Comment: @Botje is this pointer set as zeroth argument in Itanium ABI (assuming clang uses that). I did try to pass the this pointer as zeroth argument and it ended up giving incorrect result and from the debugger it is clearly not zeroth arg.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? The layout of the vtable is dependent on the ABI used by the compiler

Comment: Windows, clang compiler, 32bit

Comment: *sigh* The Windows 32-bit `thiscall` calling convention is a special case. You want `extern "thiscall"` for those functions. Or use 64-bit code. It's 2024 after all :)

Comment: `Unhandled exception at 0x00000001 in testvirtual.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000001.` -- This hasn't been mentioned so far, but this is basically a null-pointer access.

Comment: @Botje that did the trick, thank you :) Could you post this as an answer So I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, non-static methods are supposed to be called with a `this` pointer set. Nominally this is just a hidden first argument, but on x86 Windows there is a special `thiscall` calling convention that needs to be followed.

You thus need to make every method in your vtable – as well as non-virtual methods – `extern "thiscall"`:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct CalculateVtbl {
    pub sum: unsafe extern "thiscall" fn(this: *mut Calculate, a: i32, b: i32) -> i32,
}

#[repr(C)]
pub struct Calculate {
    pub vtbl: *const CalculateVtbl,
}

impl Calculate {
    #[inline(always)]
    pub unsafe fn sum(&mut self, a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
        ((*self.vtbl).sum)(self, a, b)
    }
}
```

You can put this sample in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/6EGzoG85v) and see what happens to ECX if you change `thiscall` back to `C`.

Comment: It's better to store the vtable as `&'static CalculateVtbl`.

Comment: I understand that is the better representation of vtables, but what does it buy us in this example? Does it mean taking a copy of the vtable no longer takes a reference to the `Calculate` object?

Comment: No need to use `unsafe` to access the vtable.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: While I agree, I do note that you'll still need "unsafe" to call the function anyway.